# Roaming profiles sync exception

Tags: windows, profiles, roaming

We're having server2012 with roaming profiles and everything works fine. But we want to make some
exceptions in folder synchronization. Is it possible to not sync for ex. "Downloads" folder?
Or we have to use folder redirection?
Want to know what is best practices doing that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPO -> User Configuration | Administrative Templates | System | User Profiles | Exclude directories in roaming profile

Comment: You can go ahead and "Accept the Answer", assuming its the best answer to your question :)

Comment: "You can accept your answer tomorrow" some unusual rules here :)